# Possible to hide navigation bar in tab bar controller?

Tags: ios5, uinavigationbar, segue

I have a navigation controller with a segue to a tab bar controller.  When it pushes it creates a navigation bar with a back button.  I've found code to hide the back button, but the navigation bar is still there.  How do I get rid of the navigation bar?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, 
http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Full-storyboard.png